# How can I change the servlet registration in Netbeans?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, netbeans, web.xml

I started a Dyanmic Web Project in Eclipse Juno, but now I want to continue working in Netbeans 7.3. When I create a Servlet in Eclipse, by default uses annotations (instead of registering in `web.xml`) like this :

```
@WebServlet(name = "BectyServlet", urlPatterns = {"/becty"})
```

But when I create a Servlet in Netbeans, It doesn't show the annotation and its putting the servlet name and mapping in web.xml.

How can I set my project in Netbeans to create the Servlets with annotations?

Comment: I don't do Netbeans, but this feature is specific to Servlet 3.0. Perhaps you should look for some setting in Netbeans which sets project nature to Servlet 3.0 / Java EE 6 instead of e.g. Servlet 2.5 / Java EE 5. In Eclipse exactly this thing is called the *Dynamic Web Project* facet which is available in *Project Facets* section of project's properties. If you set it in Eclipse to 2.5, then it'll also register the servlet in `web.xml` like as your Netbeans is currently doing.

Comment: You're right, in Eclipse you have facets and you can change the versions of the facets but in Netbeans I can't change the version when the project is imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Netbeans, you can set it when you create the web project. If you have an existent Eclipse Project, check if everything is set to Servlet 3.0 config. Finally you should recheck what you have done when importing the project be sure to avoid **descriptor** options